# vbulletin plugin call value

Tags: php, vbulletin

I'm using a plugin in vBulletin. This plugin stores mirror links in array or something like this im not sure really I want to display every mirror link on the page by calling it separately.

In the plugin the following code:

```
{vb:var mirrorid=$i=1}
```

Is returning the first mirror id value which is `1`; And:

```
{vb:var mirror.link}
```

Is returning the value of the mirror link.

How I can return all the mirror link value or the others directly?

I tried for example `{vb:var mirror.link=$i=3}` to display the 3rd link value but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using vb4 then you can loop through array in template like
lets you have an array 
$binaries = array( 
    0 => array( 
        'subject'    => 'Subject 1', 
        'binaryid'    => 1, 
        'groups'    => array('alt.binaries.teevee', 'alt.binaries.multimedia') `enter code here`
    ), 
    1 => array( 
        'subject'    => 'Subject 2', 
        'binaryid'    => 2, 
        'groups'    => array('alt.binaries.xvid') 
    ), 
);  

and in vb4 you can pass array to template by registering variable.Then in your template you can easily access array values like
<vb:each from="binaries" value="binary">
    {vb:raw binary.subject}
    {vb:raw binary.binaryid}
</vb:each>

if you are using VB 3.8 the you can not loop through array, you have to pass single variable to template or you can loop array in your php plugin code
```